# $Spin^c$-Dirac-operator on the 3-torus

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry, 3-manifolds, gt.geometric-topology

Consider the spin<sup>c</sup> structure on the flat standard 3-torus, which you get from the trivial (or any other) spin structure. Its associated vector bundle can be identified with a trivial bundle with fibre $\mathbb{C}^2$. spin<sup>c</sup> Dirac operators on this bundle are parametrized by one-forms and look like $D_\alpha = D_0+ic_\alpha$, where $D_0$ is the spin Dirac operator and the $c$ means Clifford multiplication.

My aim is now to find a spectral decomposition for $D_\alpha$. If α is closed, this can be easily done by reducing everything to the case where α is harmonic. The case where α is not closed seems to be more tricky, so I would like to ask the community:

1. What is the spectrum of $D_\alpha$?
2. How can you construct eigenvectors?

Thank you!

Comment: A suggestion, can you gauge transform so that $\alpha$ is nice?   Gauge transformations tend to preserve spectral decompositions.

Comment: If you decompose &alpha; as $d\beta + d^*\gamma + \delta$, where $\delta$ is harmonic, then you can "gauge away" the d\beta-Part by the usual $U(1)$-gauge. Since &delta; is constant, this gives you the solution for &alpha; closed.

I don't know what kind of gauge should work on the $d^*\gamma$-part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible unpromising start that  hints at probable headaches.   Square the  Dirac to get

$$ D_\alpha^2=  \Delta+ c(d\alpha)$$

where $c(d\alpha)$ denotes the Clifford multiplication by the $2$-form  $d\alpha$.   Note that

$$ {\rm spec}(D_\alpha^2)= \bigl(\; \mathrm{spec}(D_\alpha)\;\bigr)^2 $$

To find ${\rm spec}(D_\alpha^2)$  you need to understand spectrum of ordinary differential operators   of the form

$$ -\partial^2_\theta + A(\theta)  $$

acting on functions $u: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}^2$   where  $A(\theta)$ is a $2\times 2$ complex hermitian matrix depending smoothly  on $\theta\in S^1$.   I don't know how to find  the spectrum of such an operator but maybe you can find something in the literature.